# How to list all the library functions used by any c program after 03 optimization

Tags: c, linker, profiling, gprof

I can get the name of all user functions in assembly file, and using gprof. But I want to know how many time FFT or any other benchmark called sin function, print function and other library functions.

Comment: [systemtap](https://sourceware.org/systemtap/) can be used for this. One thing it allows you to do is run a script every time a function enters or exits. Can also do many other things.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dynamically linking and running on Linux, you can use [ltrace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ltrace):

> ltrace is a program that simply runs the specified command until it
>   exits. It intercepts and records the dynamic library calls which are
>   called by the executed process and the signals which are received by
>   that process. It can also intercept and print the system calls
>   executed by the program.